# Unable to GeneratCode with Coded UI Test Builder in VS 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to generate Coded UI Tests, but when I click the "Generate Code" button I get an error dialog with the message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
I know the question is kinda vague, but that's all the info I've got. 
Has someone encountered a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few basic things to try,

- Make Sure you build the code first.
- Make sure you are within a [TestMethod]
- Check that the top of your class has [CodedUITest]
- Are you using all your references (eg. using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting)

Let me know if it doesn't work and try and get more info.

Comment: Tried it all, didn't work out.
One important info: I'm using Chrome to record the actions, and I read somewhere that CodedUI works with IE only in most cases. Maybe that's the problem :/

Comment: that could be it, I've only ever used IE

Comment: After some research it does seem that IE is the only that works for it. And that sucks haha